# How to set a goal that only counts two specific pages visited in succession?

Tags: content-testing, goals, experience-optimization

How do I set up a goal that uses a rule in Sitecore that only counts those users who have visited two pages in succession? It's important that I exclude all traffic that haven't visited these pages in succession.

For example:
- first page visited: www.abc.com/page-1

and then

- second page visited: www.abc.com/page-2

Why: 
I am trying to A/B test a Call-to-Action button on the 1st page that links through to the 2nd page. Both pages will get high volumes of traffic to them everyday from other sources so I need to ensure that I only include the traffic who click on the CTA button.

Is the best way to do this in goals or in something else in Sitecore?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to do this by editing the link of your call to action in sitecore. 
In the querystring value of the link, enter in: sc_trk=goalname
(so if your goal is named "LinkAction1" , then enter sc_trk=LinkAction1)
Save and publish that, and it will only trigger that goal if a user clicks that call to action button.

[image: insert link with goal trigger]

Comment: Thank you @-YesIRebootedAlready and this would work for SiteCore 8.2? 

Also @YesIRebootedAlready - Is there a condition or set of conditions that will achieve the same result in the Create Rule area of a goal? That would be my preference if I was using this sort of goal heavily across the site.

Comment: @Mark This would work for sitecore 8.2. I believe the create rule area of the goal doesn't work in the way you expect. It's used to apply rules **after** the goal is triggured... it doesn't set the condition for a goal to trigger. To get that type of functionality, it would require some custom pipeline coding.